# CSS layout: right-floating #sidebar which comes after #main in markup

Tags: css, layout

I'v found an exact same question as what I'm going to ask.

[Right-floated sidebar with main content flowed around - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268093/right-floated-sidebar-with-main-content-flowed-around-how)

The question is asked in **2008**, and I'm wondering if this could be done with pure CSS after almost 3 years.

Is the accepted answer (with Javascript) still the only way to achieve this layout?

Comment: The answer to this is probably going to depend on the browser support you want. Can you confirm?

Comment: Other than vague SEO benefits, why can't the sidebar markup just come before the content?

Comment: Content-first SEO is no longer a a big factor for search engines.

Comment: @shanethehat I'm expecting a cross-browser solution. ok, we can forget about ie6, or maybe ie7.

Comment: Not much has changed to CSS in this regard, so I'm pretty sure you're going to get either an unstable solution or a javascript one - not sure what shanethehat is alluding to but I'd like to hear it.

Comment: @JamWaffles yes, SEO is the only reason I'm doing this.

Comment: @Diodeus wow, I didn't know that. any solid reference?

Comment: There is really no point in putting the navigation markup after the content for SEO purposes. As @Diodeus said above, it's not really a concern anymore. If you have search-worthy content, it will turn up on Google.

Comment: See: http://www.finishjoomla.com/blog/41/does-source-code-ordering-still-matter-for-seo/

Comment: @wesley - I was alluding to CSS Exclusions, specifically Example 7.2.A towards the bottom of this page: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-exclusions/. Sadly I can't get a working example in any browser yet, much less IE!

Comment: @Diodeus The author himself answered his own question at the very last paragraph: _Until conclusive evidence has proven otherwise, I think it is still best to use source ordered code...we cannot be sure enough before deciding to step away from this feature. (2011.06)_

Comment: @jamwaffles - it could've been an accessibility concern, and still should be imho

Comment: That's a good point, although having the navigation read out to you, in the case of screenreaders, before the main content might be handy.

Comment: BUT this IS relevent if thinking "mobile" first. Its quite common to want the navigation last in the source code

Answer (score 0):

It's item 3 (from the original post) that's the killer:

> Main content should precede the sidebar in the markup

Without that, it can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/nJJ8p/1/

Comment: Of course it can be done with a simple `float:right` without requirement #3, that's the whole point - having the sidebar first in markup so your actual content is indexed with higher importance.

Comment: yep, Wesley Murch's right, that's the most important requirement.